# Ubuntu Server Loses Connection Every Few Hours (Systemd-Networkd restart fixes)

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I am having trouble with a new install of ubuntu server. I configured a bonded network using systemd-networkd which works but every few hours it stops working.

**10-bond0.netdev**

```
[NetDev]
Name=bond0
Kind=bond

[Bond]
Mode=802.3ad
TransmitHashPolicy=layer3+4
```

**10.bond0.network**

```
[Match]
Name=bond1

[Network]
DHCP=yes
IgnoreCarrierLoss=3s
DNSSEC=allow-downgrade

[DHCP]
CriticalConnection=true
UseMTU=true
UseDNS=true
```

**20-enp2.network**

```
[Match]
Name=enp2s*

[Network]
Bond=bond0
PrimarySlave=true
```

When it goes down, a ping to 1.1.1.1 times out.

Calling `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` fixes the issue until the next time it goes down.

JournalCTL doesn't have much info:

```
Sep 24 23:19:58 ubuntu dockerd[2234]: time="2023-09-24T23:19:58.848298010-07:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=3fbe14e5fa152085825eda15884837103dc0309d2120ec174ff4e95032ba6b34 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks>
Sep 24 23:19:58 ubuntu containerd[2064]: time="2023-09-24T23:19:58.849335383-07:00" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=3fbe14e5fa152085825eda15884837103dc0309d2120ec174ff4e95032ba6b34
Sep 24 23:19:58 ubuntu containerd[2064]: time="2023-09-24T23:19:58.850399956-07:00" level=warning msg="cleaning up after shim disconnected" id=3fbe14e5fa152085825eda15884837103dc0309d2120ec174ff4e95032ba6b34 namespace=moby
Sep 24 23:19:58 ubuntu containerd[2064]: time="2023-09-24T23:19:58.850422459-07:00" level=info msg="cleaning up dead shim"
Sep 24 23:19:58 ubuntu containerd[2064]: time="2023-09-24T23:19:58.861310022-07:00" level=warning msg="cleanup warnings time=\"2023-09-24T23:19:58-07:00\" level=info msg=\"starting signal loop\" namespace=moby pid=84199 runtime=io.conta>
Sep 24 23:19:58 ubuntu kernel: br-c52bc0bd1c1d: port 8(vethcb79a19) entered disabled state
Sep 24 23:19:58 ubuntu kernel: veth9890882: renamed from eth0
Sep 24 23:19:58 ubuntu systemd-networkd[67041]: vethcb79a19: Lost carrier
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu systemd-networkd[67041]: vethcb79a19: Link DOWN
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu kernel: br-c52bc0bd1c1d: port 8(vethcb79a19) entered disabled state
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu kernel: vethcb79a19 (unregistering): left allmulticast mode
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu kernel: vethcb79a19 (unregistering): left promiscuous mode
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu kernel: br-c52bc0bd1c1d: port 8(vethcb79a19) entered disabled state
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu systemd[1]: run-docker-netns-de9f1c191dbc.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu systemd-networkd[67041]: vethd157647: Link UP
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu kernel: br-c52bc0bd1c1d: port 8(vethd157647) entered blocking state
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu kernel: br-c52bc0bd1c1d: port 8(vethd157647) entered disabled state
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu kernel: vethd157647: entered allmulticast mode
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu kernel: vethd157647: entered promiscuous mode
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu kernel: br-c52bc0bd1c1d: port 8(vethd157647) entered blocking state
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu kernel: br-c52bc0bd1c1d: port 8(vethd157647) entered forwarding state
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu containerd[2064]: time="2023-09-24T23:19:59.340174610-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.event.v1.publisher\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.event.v1
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu containerd[2064]: time="2023-09-24T23:19:59.340283346-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.shutdown\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.internal.v1
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu containerd[2064]: time="2023-09-24T23:19:59.340294305-07:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.ttrpc.v1.task\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.ttrpc.v1
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu containerd[2064]: time="2023-09-24T23:19:59.340496916-07:00" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/6ccb401cf778dde29f8f774d7eb55e6e554f6bee56f>
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started docker-6ccb401cf778dde29f8f774d7eb55e6e554f6bee56fa56a2708b204552d59032.scope - libcontainer container 6ccb401cf778dde29f8f774d7eb55e6e554f6bee56fa56a2708b204552d59032.
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu systemd[1]: var-lib-docker-zfs-graph-2a03199a967ef6e4679bf0a3f6c35375d871f651990efe369afc27dd8dc21333.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu kernel: eth0: renamed from veth9810974
Sep 24 23:19:59 ubuntu systemd-networkd[67041]: vethd157647: Gained carrier
Sep 24 23:20:00 ubuntu systemd-networkd[67041]: vethd157647: Gained IPv6LL
```

Just a bit about lost carrier.

I am using a Unifi Dream Machine Pro as the router, lease times are set to 7 days.

dmesg shows:

```
[ 1061.210722] br-c52bc0bd1c1d: port 9(veth9f0f7b8) entered blocking state
[ 1061.210738] br-c52bc0bd1c1d: port 9(veth9f0f7b8) entered forwarding state
[ 1061.573317] eth0: renamed from veth8dd64c5
[ 1061.633580] eth0: renamed from veth9890882
[ 1061.657483] br-c52bc0bd1c1d: port 8(vethcb79a19) entered blocking state
[ 1061.657488] br-c52bc0bd1c1d: port 8(vethcb79a19) entered forwarding state
[ 4483.973435] perf: interrupt took too long (2545 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 78500
[ 4985.341221] perf: interrupt took too long (3182 > 3181), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 62750
[ 9023.845905] perf: interrupt took too long (3999 > 3977), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
[19294.586812] bond0: (slave enp2s0f0): link status definitely down, disabling slave
[19294.586837] bond0: (slave enp2s0f1): link status definitely down, disabling slave
```

(I had to restart it to ssh into box to get it info so its currently up)
ipAddr

```
enp2s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0e:5b:47:f7:88:46 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 80:61:5f:14:f7:73
3: enp2s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0e:5b:47:f7:88:46 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 80:61:5f:14:f7:74
4: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0e:5b:47:f7:88:46 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.18/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global bond0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd10:9f58:b2f2:48fa:c5b:47ff:fef7:8846/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 1790sec preferred_lft 1790sec
    inet6 fe80::c5b:47ff:fef7:8846/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

root@ubuntu:/etc/systemd/network# systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled

```
UNIT FILE                            STATE   PRESET  
apparmor.service                     enabled enabled 
console-setup.service                enabled enabled 
containerd.service                   enabled enabled 
cron.service                         enabled enabled 
dmesg.service                        enabled enabled 
docker.service                       enabled enabled 
e2scrub_reap.service                 enabled enabled 
getty@.service                       enabled enabled 
keyboard-setup.service               enabled enabled 
networkd-dispatcher.service          enabled enabled 
rsyslog.service                      enabled enabled 
setvtrgb.service                     enabled enabled 
ssh.service                          enabled enabled 
systemd-network-generator.service    enabled enabled 
systemd-networkd-wait-online.service enabled disabled
systemd-networkd.service             enabled enabled 
systemd-pstore.service               enabled enabled 
systemd-resolved.service             enabled enabled 
systemd-timesyncd.service            enabled enabled 
ua-reboot-cmds.service               enabled enabled 
ubuntu-advantage.service             enabled enabled 
zfs-import-cache.service             enabled enabled 
zfs-load-module.service              enabled enabled 
zfs-mount.service                    enabled enabled 
zfs-share.service                    enabled enabled 
zfs-volume-wait.service              enabled enabled 
zfs-zed.service                      enabled enabled 
docker.socket                        enabled enabled 
ssh.socket                           enabled enabled 
systemd-networkd.socket              enabled enabled 
remote-fs.target                     enabled enabled 
zfs-import.target                    enabled enabled 
zfs-volumes.target                   enabled enabled 
zfs.target                           enabled enabled 
apt-daily-upgrade.timer              enabled enabled 
apt-daily.timer                      enabled enabled 
dpkg-db-backup.timer                 enabled enabled 
e2scrub_all.timer                    enabled enabled 
fstrim.timer                         enabled enabled 
logrotate.timer                      enabled enabled 
motd-news.timer                      enabled enabled 
ua-timer.timer                       enabled enabled
```

I've tried just about everything I can think of but it continuously happens. I am at a lost on what to do next or how to fix it. Can anyone help?